# Как исправить код ассемблера?

Tags: ассемблер

```
copy: 
    lodsb ;Загружаем новый символ
    cmp al, 30h ;Проверяем ноль ли это
    je output ;Если ноль - переходим к выводу строки
    stos from ;Иначе - переносим символ в новую строку
    jmp copy ;Повторяем итерацию

;Блок вывода строк
output:
    mov al, 30h ;Заносим символ ноль в регистр al
    stosb ;Заносим символ в конец строки
    mov al, '$' ;Заносим символ конца строки в регистр al
    stosb ;Добавляем после нуля символ конца строки чтобы не выводить линшний мусор
    mov ah,09h ;Переходим к выводу строки
    lea dx, msg ;Заносим адрес начала вывода
    int 21h ;Выводим строки msg и result
```

в этом куске кода нужно исправить две вещи:

- Z-строка кончается нулевым символом (кодом 0, а не 30h)
- вы не имеете право дописывать что-то к строке, чтобы вывести ее на экран, при выводе строка доступна вам как есть (начало по известному адресу, в конце - ноль) и только для чтения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> cmp al, 30h ;Проверяем ноль ли это
> je output ;Если ноль - переходим к выводу строки
> ```

Как минимум в этом месте сравнение не с тем числом.

Comment: 30h - это ASCII-код символа “0”

Comment: @Анна, но в условии говорится про символ с кодом 0, а не про нолик.

Comment: ааааа, поняла Вас

Comment: но символы с кодами 0-31 относятся к служебным, что же делать?

Comment: @Анна вам и нужен служебный символ, обозначающий конец строки